# Dynamically rendered h:inputFile using checkbox

Tags: ajax, jsf, checkbox

**Problem:** Trying to display `h:inputFile` tag based on if a checkbox for a row will display the option to upload a file. The issue arises when I want to uncheck a row (meaning to stop editing the row) and the row is still shown in edit mode.

Before editing a row:

[image: Before clicking on checkbox]

While editing a row:

[image: While editing a row]

Uncheck the row without saving changes (**issue here**):

[image: Current issue]

**Goal:** I just want to display the book information as if the user didn't want to change the book information at all (*specifically example 1*). This problem is still displayed after the user saves the changes using the `libraryBean.save()` method (*specifically example 2*).

So in short, I want the result to look like example 1 for when either the user unchecks the row or after the changes are saved.

---

**Code In Question:**

```
<h:inputFile id="file" label="file" style="margin-top: 10px"
    value="#{libraryBean.part}"
    validator="#{libraryBean.validateFile}"
    rendered="#{book.editable}"/>
```

---

**Additional Info:**

XMLNS Libraries:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

LibraryBean is `@SessionScoped`

---

**Full Code:**

```
<h:form id="frmlibrary" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty libraryBean.books}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h:dataTable value="#{libraryBean.books}" class="table table-bordered"
                         var="book" border="1" id="dtLibrary" rendered="#{not empty libraryBean.books}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="checkbox" value="#{book.editable}" onclick="submit()" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Book Cover</f:facet>
                    <image src="ImageServlet?fileID=#{book.libID}"
                           height="150" width="100" />
                    <h:inputFile id="file" label="file" style="margin-top: 10px"
                                 value="#{libraryBean.part}"
                                 validator="#{libraryBean.validateFile}"
                                 rendered="#{book.editable}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{book.title}" class="form-control"
                                 rendered="#{book.editable}" size="20"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" 
                                  rendered="#{not book.editable}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Author</f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{book.author}" class="form-control"
                                 rendered="#{book.editable}" size="20"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.author}" 
                                  rendered="#{not book.editable}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </div>
    </ui:fragment>
    <h:commandButton value="Save Library" class="btn btn-info"
                     action="#{libraryBean.save()}" rendered="#{not empty libraryBean.books}"/>
</h:form>
```

---

**Update:**

I have combined my `LibraryFileBean` with my `LibraryBean` to implement changing book covers within the `libraryBean.save()` method. I am still running into the same issue explained above.

*The code has been changed throughout this question to reflect this update! Apologies for the inconvenience this may cause*

Comment: Are the methods `isEditable()` (or `getEditable()`) and `setEditable()` from the `Book` concrete instance being called when you check/uncheck de checkbox? You can try adding a `valueChangeListener` to the checkbox and check if it's being called when checking/unchecking it.

Comment: Have you excluded all of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add this to your check box and save button `update=":dtLibrary"` by doing this the table will be rendered again and within your `save` method don't forget to set the `book.editable` property set to `false`.